# How to implement output cache for a content part (such as a widget)?

Tags: orchardcms

I have a widget with list of last news, how to cache only widget output?
OutputCache module caches whole page and for anonymous users, but in fact I need to cache only one shape output. 
What solution can be here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good idea to cache the `Shape` object itself, but you can capture the HTML output from a `Shape` and cache that.

Every Orchard `Shape` has a corresponding object called the `Metadata`.  This object contains, among other things, some event handlers that can run when the `Shape` is displaying or after it has been displayed.  By using these event handlers, it is possible to cache the output of the `Shape` on the first call to a driver.  Then for future calls to the driver, we can display the cached copy of the output instead of running through the expensive parts of the driver or template rendering.

Example:

```
using System.Web;
using DemoModule.Models;
using Orchard.Caching;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers;
using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes;

namespace DemoModule.Drivers {
    public class MyWidgetPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<MyWidgetPart> {
        private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;
        private readonly ISignals _signals;

        public MyWidgetPartDriver(
            ICacheManager cacheManager,
            ISignals signals
        ) {
            _cacheManager = cacheManager;
            _signals = signals;
        }

        public class CachedOutput {
            public IHtmlString Output { get; set; }
        }

        protected override DriverResult Display(MyWidgetPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
            return ContentShape("Parts_MyWidget", () => {
                // The cache key.  Build it using whatever is needed to differentiate the output.
                var cacheKey = /* e.g. */ string.Format("MyWidget-{0}", part.Id);

                // Standard Orchard cache manager.  Notice we get this object by reference,
                // so we can write to its field to save our cached HTML output.
                var cachedOutput = _cacheManager.Get(cacheKey, ctx => {
                    // Use whatever signals are needed to invalidate the cache.
                    _signals.When(/* e.g. */ "ExpireCache");
                    return new CachedOutput();
                });

                dynamic shape;
                if (cachedOutput.Output == null) {
                    // Output has not yet been cached, so we are going to build the shape normally
                    // and then cache the output.

                    /*
                    ... Do normal (potentially expensive) things (call DBs, call services, etc.)
                        to prep shape ...
                    */

                    // Create shape object.
                    shape = shapeHelper.Parts_MyWidget(/*...*/);

                    // Hook up an event handler such that after rendering the (potentially expensive)
                    // shape template, we capture the output to the cached output object.
                    ((ShapeMetadata) shape.Metadata).OnDisplayed(displayed => cachedOutput.Output = displayed.ChildContent);
                } else {
                    // Found cached output, so simply output it instead of building
                    // the shape normally.

                    // This is a dummy shape, the name doesn't matter.
                    shape = shapeHelper.CachedShape();

                    // Hook up an event handler to fill the output of this shape with the cached output.
                    ((ShapeMetadata)shape.Metadata).OnDisplaying(displaying => displaying.ChildContent = cachedOutput.Output);

                    // Replacing the ChildContent of the displaying context will cause the display manager
                    // to simply use that HTML output and skip template rendering.
                }

                return shape;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Note that this only caches the HTML that is generated from your shape output. Things like Script.Require(), Capture(), and other side effects that you perform in your shape templates will not be played back. This actually bit me because I tried to cache a template that required its own stylesheet, but the stylesheets would only be brought in the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Orchard supplies a service called the CacheManager, which is awesome and cool and makes caching super easy. It is mentioned in the docs, but it isn't a particularly helpful description of how to use it (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Caching). Best place to see examples would be in the Orchard core code and third party modules such as Favicon and the twitter widgets (all of them one would hope).

Luckily other nice people have gone to the effort of searching orchards code for you and writing nice little blog posts about it. The developer of the LatestTwitter widget wrote a neat post: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/01/21/Writing-an-Orchard-widget-LatestTwitter.aspx . So did Richard of NogginBox: http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/orchard-caching-by-time . And of course Bertrand has a helpful post on the subject as well: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/02/16/caching-items-in-orchard.aspx

Comment: My question is about output cache, like OutputCache module do it, but not about record caching. 
In MVC we have OutputCacheAttribute what we can to use for partial views. I'm looking same stuff, but for shapes.